# Написание спортивных званий

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно писать сокращенно спортивные звания, например, мастер спорта - мс, м.с. МС? Я совсем запуталась.

Answer (score 1):

Вот в таблице (а можнт и не только в таблице) как раз лучше - МС, КМС, МСМК, ЗМС и т.д. Это будет не сокращение, а аббревиатура в роли условного наименования. В примечании можно указать расшифровку.

Шахматистов там нет?  Если есть, то ещё ММ, НГ, МГ - межденародный мастер, национальный и международный гроссмейтер.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Т.е., насколько я понимаю, в тексте правильнее писать м.с., а в таблице - МС?

Comment: Я бы не говорил о слове "правильнее". Правильнее - не сокращать вообще. Но в таблицах приходится идти на компромисс - и обилие точек не способствует восприятию.  
Что касается "гладкого" текста - то тут надо подумать, столь ли вообще необходимо "сокращение". Честно говоря, вариант "з. м." мне не нравится уже тем, что по правилам его придётся писать с пробелом. Наверное надо посмотреть, что это вообще за текст. Если, скажем, строчка в календаре, то очень может быть, что пойдет именно "змс".

Answer (score 0):

Слова сокращаются на согласную перед гласной. После сокращения ставится точка. Получается, м.с. Только зачем все сокращать?

Comment: Спасибо большое! Там таблица с результатами, неизменяемая форма. :))) Везде написано МС, КМС и т.д. Меня что-то сомнение взяло, а как правильно писать сомневалась.